# Sourcing script does not print any output to the console

Tags: r

I am using Ubuntu inside Windows XP using VirtualBox, and I installed R properly. I am using a library called `psych` for this. The following is my code:

```
impact <- read.table("stats1.ex.02.txt", header=T)
class(impact)
describe(impact)
```

I am taking Statistics One course on coursera.org and the Prof gives this `txt` file to work with. When I run this in R, using `source("test.R")` (where `test.R` is the filename I gave), 
nothing happens. What could be problem here ?

Comment: Did anyone else gravitate to this question because of its author?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using `source("test.R", echo=TRUE)` or adding `print` to whatever you want printed after sourcing your script. Thus, your script might be:

```
impact<- read.table("stats1.ex.02.txt",header=T)
print(class(impact))
print(describe(impact))
```

Comment: Thanks mrdwab, that worked.. By the way, I didn't get any email notification for the replies here. How would I change that settings ?