# Summary command not returning in R script

Tags: r, summary, statnet

It seems like the `summary` command in R is coming up blank whenever I run it in a script, even though it works fine in the command line.

Here's my script:

```
suppressMessages(library("statnet"))

#Simple example using a 3-node network
n<-network.initialize(3, directed=T) #generate an empty 3 node network
n[1,2]<-1  #assign a single link between node 1 and node 2
gplot(n)  #plot the network

e1<-ergm(n~edges)  #conduct an ergm using only the edges term

summary(e1)
```

And no, removing `suppressMessages` doesn't help. 
The result of this script is this:

```
root@user:~/NetworkStatsData$ r test.R
Evaluating log-likelihood at the estimate.
```

That's it. Absolutely nothing from the `summary` command. Now, when I run the exact same commands in command line, I get this result:

```
root@user:~/NetworkStatsData$ R

R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10) -- "Wooden Christmas-Tree"
Copyright (C) 2015 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

> suppressMessages(library("statnet"))
> n<-network.initialize(3, directed=T)
> n[1,2]<-1
> gplot(n)
> e1<-ergm(n~edges)
Evaluating log-likelihood at the estimate. 
> summary(e1)

==========================
Summary of model fit
==========================

Formula:   n ~ edges

Iterations:  4 out of 20 

Monte Carlo MLE Results:
      Estimate Std. Error MCMC % p-value
edges   -1.609      1.095      0   0.202

     Null Deviance: 8.318  on 6  degrees of freedom
 Residual Deviance: 5.407  on 5  degrees of freedom

AIC: 7.407    BIC: 7.198    (Smaller is better.) 
>
```

Which is what I want to happen when running the script. Why is it acting differently for one than the other?

Comment: Check this answer out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400976/sourcing-script-does-not-print-any-output-to-the-console

Comment: Alright, I guess that makes sense

Comment: @Nathan It looks like you're using littler on the command line.  Have you just tried adding the '-p' command line argument.  Does `r -p test.R` get you what you want?